# PDF24 saves rubbish PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe, extract, adobe-reader

this subject was raised few times before but I couldn't find anything relevant in terms of way of saving PDF.
I'm trying to save document as PDF, using PDF24. This document is just pop-up from Chrome.

When I'm trying to print it (ctr+P), and save it as PDF, using PDF24 it looks good in Adobe Reader, but results in rubbish text when copy-paste it to notepad:
[image]

One explanation which I've found was that fonts are not installed on my workstation, but according to Inspect tool in Chrome (in original document - before printing it) - fonts are standard, and all are installed on my workstation.

[image]

That's why I wonder - is it a metter of Configuration PDF24 tool, or is it a bug win PDF24, and it will not work with this tool?

Any support is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with the PDF24 printer. The problem sits in Chrome. There is an open bug which has not been fixed so far. When printing in Chrome, chrome does not send the required font information via the printer interface. Thus, the PDF printer does not have the required unicode information and copying text in the PDF ends in garbled text.

Comment: You might be right - It seems to be working fine in IE